# Laravel 5.x & Angular X

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5

I need some advice.
I want to develop a website with laravel 5.6 and angular 5.
Is it a good idea? For big project?

Also about integration, What is the better way?
1. install laravel then angular ...
2. install angular and then in api create laravel project

Or some other way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

integration of angular & laravel is good for big project and if you wanna work with this two thing it is not important install what first (if you're not familiar with laravel and right now you wanna learn it my suggest is to use node js instead of laravel, however laravel is absolutely fine and awesome and can work properly with angular)

for connecting laravel and angular take look at this [page](https://appdividend.com/2017/09/22/laravel-5-5-angular-4-tutorial-example-scratch/#Step_6_Resolve_CORS_problem)
and use nginx for web server according [this site](http://digitalreveries.in/2016/12/install-laravel-nginx-php-fpm/)